# Can not find class DriverSource

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

I am running automated tests in Chrome with Serenity BDD (Selenium), but having **can not find symbol: class DriverSource** problem while implementing customer webdriver codes.(trying to test it on chrome mobile emulator)
Does anyone know what's the issue. Thanks

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MobileEmulation implements DriverSource {

@Override
public WebDriver newDriver() {
    try {
            String ChromeDriverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/chromdrive/chromedriver.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ChromeDriverPath);

            Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");

            Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            return driver;
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean takesScreenshots() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't imported the DriverSource class:

```
import net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverSource;
```